# Alternatives OBS - Open Broadcaster Software

Tags: software-recommendation, alternative

I have a problem. OBS [Open Broadcaster Software] doesn't work on my laptop because it does not support OpenGL 3.5. I want to get into [livecoding](https://www.livecoding.tv/hackro/), so are there any alternatives to OBS?

Log error OBS

```
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale/es-ES.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale/es-ES.ini
info: Using preferred locale 'es-ES'
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Default.qss
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Default.qss
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/license/gplv2.txt
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/license/gplv2.txt
info: Processor: 4 logical cores
info: Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 480  @ 2.67GHz
info: Physical Memory: 5640MB Total
info: Kernel Version: Linux 4.4.0-24-generic
info: Distribution: "Ubuntu" "16.04"
QObject::connect: invalid null parameter
info: OBS 0.14.2 (linux)
info: ---------------------------------
info: ---------------------------------
info: audio settings reset:
    samples per sec: 44100
    speakers:        2
error: X Error: GLXBadFBConfig
error: Failed to create OpenGL context.
error: Failed to create context!
error: device_create (GL) failed
error: Failed to initialize video:  Unspecified error
info: Freeing OBS context data
info: == Profiler Results =============================
info: run_program_init: 1458.89 ms
info:  ┣OBSApp::AppInit: 3.954 ms
info:  ┃ ┗OBSApp::InitLocale: 1.561 ms
info:  ┗OBSApp::OBSInit: 85.229 ms
info:    ┣obs_startup: 2.215 ms
info:    ┗OBSBasic::OBSInit: 28.661 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitBasicConfig: 0.709 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::ResetAudio: 0.166 ms
info:      ┗OBSBasic::ResetVideo: 27.652 ms
info: obs_hotkey_thread(25 ms): min=0.131 ms, median=0.38 ms, max=9.193 ms, 99th percentile=9.193 ms, 100% below 25 ms
info: audio_thread(Audio): min=0 ms, median=0.009 ms, max=0.027 ms, 99th percentile=0.027 ms
info: =================================================
info: == Profiler Time Between Calls ==================
info: obs_hotkey_thread(25 ms): min=25.215 ms, median=25.484 ms, max=34.269 ms, 52.0833% within ±2% of 25 ms (0% lower, 47.9167% higher)
info: =================================================
info: Number of memory leaks: 128
```

Comment: I would suggest asking your question [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can't find anything: what OpenGL version does it support? Perhaps it would make sense to just use latest development drivers, with, perhaps later OpenGL?

Comment: because Intel® Ironlake Mobile  don't support opengl 3.5 @Hi-Angel

Comment: @DavidHackro idk what's not enough till 3.5 support, but Ironlake Mobile seem to be supported by the i965 driver *(not sure)* [which has almost OpenGL-4.3.](https://mesamatrix.net/). So [you could try the trick](http://mesa-users.freedesktop.narkive.com/MhacarLn/strangely-low-opengl#post2) with faking OpenGL version, and see if that works.

Comment: but not work https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/failed-to-initialize-video-unspecified-error-for-obs-linux-mint.37334/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Solution](https://github.com/David-Hackro/streaming-ffmeg)!

**First**:

Install FFMPEG

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

**Second**:

Create a file named "obs-fix.sh" containing the following

```shell
INRES="1366x768" # input resolution
OUTRES="1366x768" # output resolution
FPS="30" # target FPS
GOP="30" # i-frame interval, should be double of FPS, 
GOPMIN="15" # min i-frame interval, should be equal to fps, 
THREADS="4" # max 6
CBR="1000k" # constant bitrate (should be between 1000k - 3000k)
QUALITY="ultrafast"  # one of the many FFMPEG preset
AUDIO_RATE="44100"
STREAM_KEY="***************************"
#SERVER="rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/"
#SERVER="rtmp://live.justin.tv/app/"
SERVER="rtmp://usmedia3.livecoding.tv:1935/livecodingtv/"

ffmpeg -f x11grab -s "$INRES" -r "$FPS" -i :0.0 -f alsa -i pulse -f flv -ac 2 -ar $AUDIO_RATE \
 -vcodec libx264 -g $GOP -keyint_min $GOPMIN -b:v $CBR -minrate $CBR -maxrate $CBR -pix_fmt yuv420p\
 -s $OUTRES -preset $QUALITY -tune film -acodec libmp3lame -threads $THREADS -strict normal \
 -bufsize $CBR "$SERVER$STREAM_KEY"
```

and execute this [script](https://github.com/David-Hackro/streaming-ffmeg) with `./obs-fix.sh`

Work fine in ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04

Comment: does this work with a two monitor setup?